# R create a 1/0 T/F contrast-_like_ matrix / new variable based on column value

Tags: r, matrix

In R, how can we programatically create new variables based on the unique values in another column?

A simple example of the data frame where we might start:

```
structure(list(obsNum = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("obs1", "obs10", "obs11", "obs2", 
"obs3", "obs4", "obs5", "obs6", "obs7", "obs8", "obs9"), class = "factor"), 
    charVector = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("obsNum", 
"charVector"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

obsNum  charVector
  obs1        blue
  obs2       green
  obs3         red
  obs4       green
  obs5       green
  obs6         red
  obs7        blue
  obs8        blue
  obs9       green
 obs10       green
 obs11         red
```

and where I'd like to end up:

```
structure(list(obsNum = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("obs1", "obs10", "obs11", "obs2", 
"obs3", "obs4", "obs5", "obs6", "obs7", "obs8", "obs9"), class = "factor"), 
    charVector = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red"), class = "factor"), 
    blue = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), green = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), red = c(0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("obsNum", 
"charVector", "blue", "green", "red"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

obsNum charVector blue green red
  obs1       blue    1     0   0
  obs2      green    0     1   0
  obs3        red    0     0   1
  obs4      green    0     1   0
  obs5      green    0     1   0
  obs6        red    0     0   1
  obs7       blue    1     0   0
  obs8       blue    1     0   0
  obs9      green    0     1   0
 obs10      green    0     1   0
 obs11        red    0     0   1
```

I'm very open to multi-step solutions, e.g.: first create the new variables; then evaluate each new variable (name) against `charVec`, one variable at a time.  It's also completely fine to create a separate `data.frame` that could be `cbind` 'ed to the start file, assuming the order of the observations would be retained.

Thanks in advance and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cbind(dat, model.matrix(~ . - 1, dat["charVector"]))

##    obsNum charVector charVectorblue charVectorgreen charVectorred                                                                                                                                                                          
## 1    obs1       blue              1               0             0                                                                                                                                                                          
## 2    obs2      green              0               1             0                                                                                                                                                                          
## 3    obs3        red              0               0             1                                                                                                                                                                          
## 4    obs4      green              0               1             0                                                                                                                                                                          
## 5    obs5      green              0               1             0                                                                                                                                                                          
## 6    obs6        red              0               0             1                                                                                                                                                                          
## 7    obs7       blue              1               0             0                                                                                                                                                                          
## 8    obs8       blue              1               0             0                                                                                                                                                                          
## 9    obs9      green              0               1             0                                                                                                                                                                          
## 10  obs10      green              0               1             0                                                                                                                                                                          
## 11  obs11        red              0               0             1
```

Comment: `@Jake Burkhead` and `@Ananda Mahto` :  both great and workable solutions.  Sorry for the delay in responding.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `table` (and `as.data.frame.matrix` to retain the tabular format):

```
x <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
cbind(df, x[match(df$obsNum, rownames(x)), ])
#       obsNum charVector blue green red
# obs1    obs1       blue    1     0   0
# obs2    obs2      green    0     1   0
# obs3    obs3        red    0     0   1
# obs4    obs4      green    0     1   0
# obs5    obs5      green    0     1   0
# obs6    obs6        red    0     0   1
# obs7    obs7       blue    1     0   0
# obs8    obs8       blue    1     0   0
# obs9    obs9      green    0     1   0
# obs10  obs10      green    0     1   0
# obs11  obs11        red    0     0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using a loop to define the 0/1 variables.  It takes advantage of the fact that TRUE/FALSE -> 0/1 when converted to numbers.

```
colors <- unique(df$charVector)
to.append <- matrix(0, nrow = dim(df[1]), ncol = length(colors))
colnames(to.append) <- colors

i <- 0
for(color in colors){
  i <- i + 1
  to.append[, i] <- df$charVector == color
}
df <- cbind(df, to.append)
```